Ways of estimating the expectation of sum of geometrical distributions.
Consider $w_i \sim \operatorname{Geom}(p_{\text{ }i})$ (with support $\mathbb{N}_0$) independent r.v. with $p_i$ is increasing sequence and $\displaystyle \sum_{i = 1}^M p_{\text{ }i} = 1$.
I want to estimate the upper tail of expectations: $\bigstar = \displaystyle \sum_{i = (1-p)M}^{M} \mathbb{E}(w_i) = \sum_{i = (1-p)M}^{M} \frac{p_i}{1 - p_i}$, where $p \in [0, 1]$ (assume $pM \in \mathbb{N}$).
My bounds:

Lower bound is: $\bigstar \ge \frac{p_{(1-p)M}}{1 - p_{(1-p)M}} pM$ (since the $f(x) = \frac{x}{1 - x}$ is increasing and the same for $\{p_i\}$).

Upper bound is following: assume all mass of probabilities lies in $[(1-p)M, M]$ part, then $\bigstar \le \frac{pM}{pM - 1}$.


But maybe there are more tight bounds? Or any ideas?

Looks weird. Why $(1-p)M$ instead of simply (say) $A$? Is there some relationship between $p$ and $p_i$ ?

@leonbloy no connection between $p$ and $p_i$. Sequence $p_i$ settle a distribution and $p$ is an upper percentile of the $100p$% largest values of $p_i$.

OK, then you should clarify that the index runs up to $M$
